# .octaverc file on Windows XP

Tags: octave

I place this code in octaverc in home directory which is setup previously. I am confused, in the book it talks about .octaverc with a dot in front and I just name my file octaverc. This code does not load on start and it should. If i execute this in command line it is fine but I want it to load automatically each time, and it does not. So my home directory is fine, and I have octaverc file in there with this code. What is wrong? I am on Windows XP.

```
PS1 (">> ");
edit mode "async";
```

Comment: You should accept an answer to your other questions if it solved your problems (as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask))

Answer (score 3):

Filenames beginning with a dot are hidden files on Unix/Linux. It's often used for configuration files. Apparently, the same name was kept for Windows (I only used it on Linux). You should try with a dot.

Comment: At least on Windows 7, Octave loads config from "%userprofile%\.octaverc"